# What is the best way to process 25k API calls in 1 hour?

Tags: queue, message-queue, distributed, distributed-computing

I'm working on a tracking site that that tracks a player's levels for a game from day to day.

It's going to have to process around 25,000 API calls once a day. I'd like to be able to get this done in 1 hour but I would be okay with processing them all in 2 hours for now.

This is the API I would need to call for each player in my database to get their information: http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=Zezima

My site and database are hosted on a VPS.

My thought on how to achieve this is to spin up a handful of Digital Ocean VPS instances when the time comes to make the API calls and have my main VPS distribute the API calls across the DO instances which will make the API calls and insert the results back into my database.

Comment: What is your worry? 25K in an hour is not more than 7 per second. I guess one server can handle that.

Comment: 25k things per hour is less than 7 per second. Is that really so much?

Comment: The more interesting part is if if runescape.com can (or wants to..) handle your load :)

Comment: They rate limit and I start getting empty responses which is why I beleive I need to use multiple servers to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelization is your friend here.  Pool your queue listeners and have them run on a machine with adequate CPU and memory.

How fast is your process?  Completing 25,000 transactions in one hour means 7 per second.  Do you have timing data to help guide the number of instances you'll need?

I'm assuming that your database will allow simultaneous INSERTs.  You don't want those getting in each other's way.